# Monk not inserting properly?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoskin, monk

mongo:

```
> db.version()
3.0.8
```

npm & node:

```
npm info using npm@3.3.6
npm info using node@v5.0.0
```

Config file:

```
config.mongodb = {
    host: '127.0.0.1',
    port: '27017',
    db: 'mytest',
    monk: {
        'auto_reconnect': true,
        'poolSize': 5
    }
};
```

My main file:

```
var config = require('./config');

var monk = require('monk');

var db = monk(config.mongodb.url, config.mongodb.monk);
var languages = db.get('languages');

languages.insert({
    a: 'b'
}, function (err, doc) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log('doc: ' + JSON.stringify(doc));
});
```

package.json:

```
{
    "name": "instanty",
    "version": "0.1.1",
    "description": "",
    "dependencies": {
        "co": "^4.6.0",
        "co-monk": "^1.0.0",
        "cookie-parser": "^1.4.0",
        "forever": "^0.15.1",
        "geoip-lite": "^1.1.6",
        "handlebars": "^4.0.5",
        "jsonwebtoken": "^5.4.1",
        "jwt-simple": "^0.4.0",
        "koa": "^1.1.2",
        "koa-better-ratelimit": "^2.1.2",
        "koa-bodyparser": "^2.0.1",
        "koa-conditional-get": "^1.0.3",
        "koa-generic-session": "^1.10.0",
        "koa-handlebars": "^0.5.7",
        "koa-mount": "^1.3.0",
        "koa-passport": "^2.0.1",
        "koa-redis": "^1.0.1",
        "koa-router": "^5.3.0",
        "koa-static": "^1.5.2",
        "lodash": "^3.10.1",
        "mongodb": "^2.0.45",
        "mongoskin": "^2.0.0",
        "monk": "^1.0.1",
        "monk": "https://github.com/vccabral/monk.git",
        "nodemon": "^1.8.1",
        "passport": "^0.3.2",
        "passport-http-bearer": "^1.0.1",
        "passport-local": "^1.0.0",
        "socket.io": "^1.3.7",
        "socketio-jwt": "^4.3.3"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "del": "2.1.0",
        "gulp": "3.9.0",
        "gulp-autoprefixer": "3.1.0",
        "gulp-concat": "2.6.0",
        "gulp-concat-css": "2.2.0",
        "gulp-imagemin": "2.4.0",
        "gulp-less": "3.0.5",
        "gulp-minify-css": "1.2.2",
        "gulp-notify": "2.2.0",
        "gulp-uglify": "1.5.1",
        "imagemin-pngquant": "4.2.0",
        "run-sequence": "1.1.5"
    },
    "main": "app.js",
    "scripts": {
        "start": "node --harmony app.js"
    },
    "author": "",
    "license": "ISC"
}
```

I get "doc: undefined". Is there something I'm missing? My mongodb is up and running.

Comment: FWIW, Monk async functions [return promises](https://www.npmjs.com/package/monk#promises). Also, try logging `err` too...

Comment: @robertklep Oh wow, I've been using co-monk. Updated the question as that simple code still results in the same result.

Comment: I can't reproduce this with `monk@1.0.1` against MongoDB 3, it's logging a proper document. Are you setting any particular monk options?

Comment: @robertklep updated with package.json!

Answer (score 0):

You have two `monk` dependencies:

```
"monk": "^1.0.1",
"monk": "https://github.com/vccabral/monk.git",
```

The latter is giving me the same result (`doc` being undefined), so I would suggest removing it and sticking with the one published to the NPM repository (`monk@1.0.1`).

Comment: It's needed I'm afraid to to a bug. I'll get back with correct github issue number

Comment: Alright good to see another is getting the same results. I'll update the issue in github.

Comment: @KarlMorrison playing devil's advocate here, but do you actually _need_ `monk`?

Comment: Haha no worries! I'm actually going to drop it now due to this issue alone as I can wrap them in promises myself! Would perhaps be nice for others though!

Comment: The native MongoDB driver also supports promises nowadays (you can even provide an existing promises implementation, like `bluebird`, if you like).